# Using stack navigator in react navigation, how can I make a screen go away?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

### **Problem**

I am creating a social media type app in react native, where the user can create posts, and view other's posts. When the user creates a post, a new "create post" stack navigator screen is shown. I want it to be so that when a user posts their post, the create post screen automatically goes away.

### **Question**

How I can make it so that when a user presses a button on a screen above another screen, the stack navigator screen automatically disappears and takes you back to the default screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navigation.goBack`
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#goBack-Close-the-active-screen-and-move-back

Closes the active screen

> Optionally provide a key, which specifies the route to go back from.
>   By default, goBack will close the route that it is called from. If the
>   goal is to go back anywhere, without specifying what is getting
>   closed, call .goBack(null);